# iPhone Accelerometer Sensitivity

Tags: iphone, ios4, cordova, accelerometer

I have a very strange question. I have two iPhone 4S phones and i am using the accelerometer to move a character in a game. However in one phone the character moves faster than the other. Does the sensitivity of the Accelerometer differ from phone to phone/software versions etc?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but it might have something to do with your question:

```
CGFloat samplesPerSecond = 30;
[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate: self];
[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval: 1.0 / samplesPerSecond];
```

This wil limit the amount of times the phone will give you a call on the callback method. The standard value of this setting might be different in the different iOS versions (not proven, just a thought).